# In Fiber Optic Telephone line, how light signals are converted to the voice signals?

Tags: cables, modem, optical-fibre, telecommunications

I have been learning how internet data travels in different kind of Broadband access.

In case of telephone broadband, voice signals travels through the telephone line. At the user premise, the modem coverts the voice signals into digital information. The Fiber Optic medium transfers light pulses. Now, here are few questions in my mind after learning that:

**(1)** If the telephone infrastructure is migrated from copper wires to the Fiber Optic cables, then how the data transmission will take place ? Because, the Fiber Optic medium transfers light pulses

**(2)** Will I need a different kind of MODEM if I migrate my internet connection from ADSL broadband to Fiber Optic access ?

**(3)** In case of Television cable internet, what kind of signals travels through the cable ? And what makes Cable internet faster than ADSL ?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: *Because, the Fiber Optic medium transfers light pulses* You can also modulate an analog broadband signal (like 50 MHz - 1 GHz) onto a laser and transfer that through an optic fiber. That signal can contain TV signals plus IP/Internet (and thus VOIP and thus a telephone signal). Millions of people use that in my country. **Morale**: don't make assumptions on something you do not fully understand, **not all Fiber Optic media use pulses.**

Comment: only 1 ghz? The optical communications bands have several THz of bandwidth, and getting modulators and detectors with 50+ GHz of bandwidth is not particularly difficult.

Comment: AFAIK, your "normal" voice signal doesn't actually go across the fibre. It goes to your modem and then your modem converts it into a VoIP call (Internet call). That's why your phone will stop working if your power goes out.

Answer (score 1):

1) Telephone conversations have been digitized within the central office (CO) for decades since [electronic switching systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_switching_system) (ESS) starting replacing electromechanical systems like crossbar and step.

This digitizing of the analog signal is done by sampling the voice signal at 8 kHz per second using [pulse code modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) (PCM).  It is the same scheme used to digitize audio for compact discs (although the telephone companies sample at a much lower rate -- typically [8 kHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signal_1#Bandwidth), vs [44.1 kHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_disc#Audio_CD) for CD's.

The digitizing of telephone links was then extended to long distance trunk lines between CO's.  They use [Time Division Multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing) (TDM) to allow several conversations over one pair of wires.  At first copper lines were still used, then this was replaced by fiber optic inks.

This left only analog lines from the CO to the subscriber's home. Each subscriber line interface did digital to analog conversion. Now copper is being replaced by fiber optic links also, also using TDM.  In addition to time division multiplexing, [frequency division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-division_multiplexing) (FDM)is used to create multiple TDM channels, using different carrier frequencies.

Initially fiber optic was provided to the subscriber's neighborhood, where there would be a cabinet containing the fiber to analog interface to copper pairs going into the subscriber's home.   This is now being upgraded so this interface is located in the subscriber's home, allowing a higher bandwidth connection.  The disadvantage is this interface must now be powered by the subscriber, leaving it vulnerable to power outages.  So this interfaces usually have a battery backup.

2) Yes, you would need different modems.

3) Cable has been historically faster then DSL because it used coaxial cable which has a higher bandwidth than copper.  Cable also uses FDM to share its internet services with television offerings. But with DSL fiber optic direct into the home, this should change.  Cable also has to share its bandwidth among several customers in a neighborhood, so when internet traffic is high, the download speed for each customer suffers.  This is in contrast to DSL, where each customer has a dedicated channel to the CO (whether cable or fiber).  For this reason, cable companies are reluctant to provide static IP's to their customers (which allows the customer to set up servers), while most DSL installations allows this practice.